I'm trying to login to Slack with Selenium and Chrome in headless mode, but it's too slow and doesn't load
I'm using Selenium to login to Slack on Chrome with headless mode. I tried the test in normal mode and it works fine, nothing is too slow. However, when it's headless, it can enter the email and the code sent on email, but when it moves to a different tab (to enter the workspace), it keeps loading forever. Chrome version is 129.0.6668.89, and Selenium version is 4.11. OS is Ubuntu 20.04.
I took a screenshot (attached) and nothing seems suspicious. I have tried adding the following browser options:
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-save-password-bubble");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--headless=new");
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
        options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
        options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
        options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");

But none of them made any change. I have also checked Wireshark for logs, and an ICMP ureachable port was appearing, not sure if this is relevant though. Note that the test was working fine at first, but it seems that some changes have been made to the VPN and/or the server, and everything broke after that. We tried reverting the changes, but it seems it hasn't improved the situation. Do you have any idea on what else could be the issue?
